# Array of TableRows in table layout

Tags: android

Is it possible to use TableRow like this:

That is array of TableRows. This must be inside table layout where table layout is nested inside linear layout.

```
TableRow[] tr = new TableRow[dimension];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes... this is abosutely possible in Android . TableRow is a class and you are trying to make an array of objects of a class .

Comment: Can i use 2d array for TextView

Comment: yes... 2D array for TextView is possible... Eg.: TextView textView[][] = new TextView[2][2];

Answer (score 0):

Yes Absolutely Possible. check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18207470/adding-table-rows-dynamically-in-android) link & try this code.

```
public void init(){
TableLayout ll = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.displayLinear);


for (int i = 0; i <2; i++) {

    TableRow row= new TableRow(this);
    TableRow.LayoutParams lp = new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    row.setLayoutParams(lp);
    checkBox = new CheckBox(this);
    tv = new TextView(this);
    addBtn = new ImageButton(this);
    addBtn.setImageResource(R.drawable.add);
    minusBtn = new ImageButton(this);
    minusBtn.setImageResource(R.drawable.minus);
    qty = new TextView(this);
    checkBox.setText("hello");
    qty.setText("10");
    row.addView(checkBox);
    row.addView(minusBtn);
    row.addView(qty);
    row.addView(addBtn);
    ll.addView(row,i);
}}
```

Check Answer Posted by Fredigato in that link. Hope this helps.

Comment: is multidimensional possible

Comment: What does multidimensional means For TABLE LAYOUT having TABLE ROW? from above code you can add dynamic number of TABLEROW in TABLE LAYOUT but i am not getting multidimensional Word for TABLELAYOUT.