# Set the textview in a dynamic tableview

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-studio, android-tablelayout

I have a layout for a fragment which contains a `textview` inside a `tableview`, and I want to set its text whenever a new row is added.

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.home_fragment,container,false);

            doctorNameTextView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.doctorNameTextView);

            tableLayout = (TableLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.tableLayout1);
            tableLayout.removeAllViews();
            showDoctorList();

            return v;
        }



public void showDoctorList() {
    String result = "Match Found";

    context = this.getActivity();

    MyDBHandler dbHandler = new MyDBHandler(context, null, null, 1);

    ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> docArray = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();

    DoctorDataModel doctor = null;
    try {
        doctor = dbHandler.showDoctors();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    if (doctor != null) {

        docArray = doctor.getDocArray();

        for(int i = 0; i < docArray.size(); i++) {

            TableRow row = new TableRow(getActivity());
            row.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

            for(int j = 1; j < docArray.get(i).size(); j++) {

                if(j == 1) {
                    result = "Dr. " + docArray.get(i).get(j) + " ";
                } else {
                    result = docArray.get(i).get(j) + " ";
                }
                doctorNameTextView.setText(result);
            }
            tableLayout.addView(row);
        }
    }

}
```

So How do I set the textview inside the dynamic tableview?

Comment: Already doing same what problem u are getting using current code?

Comment: The app crashes because of this code right here doctorNameTextView.setText(result);

Comment: Where is `doctorNameTextView ` TextView inside `TableLayout ` ?

Comment: please can you post the logcat output?

Comment: Yes I have an XML which contains a TableLayout that has TextView with id = doctorNameTextView

Comment: Look to answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18207470/adding-table-rows-dynamically-in-android. You can also use xml layout for TableRow. Search for layout inflater