# ScrollView is cutting off beginning of text

Tags: android, android-layout, scrollview, android-view, android-tablelayout

I followed this piece of code written by Aby in another question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22682248/5915747

The beginning of my text is being cut off on the left side of my screen. I'm missing quite a bit of info and not sure how to fix it, I have tried everything that worked for others but it has not worked for me.

popup.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/scrollviewtest"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
tools:context="com.info.PopupActivity"
android:background="#f0f0f0"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

  <HorizontalScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/rel_layout"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TableLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/table_layout"
            android:background="#80000000"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

        </TableLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

  </HorizontalScrollView>

</ScrollView>
```

init method:

```
 public void init() {

    View popupview = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.popup, null);
    popupWindow = new PopupWindow(
            popupview, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
    );
    popupWindow.showAtLocation(popupview, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
    popup_shown[0] = true;

    TableLayout tableLayout = (TableLayout) popupview.findViewById(R.id.table_layout);

    TableRow row0 = new TableRow(this);

    TextView text0 = new TextView(this);
    text0.setText("Test Header1");
    row0.addView(text0);

    TextView text1 = new TextView(this);
    text1.setText("Test Header2");
    row0.addView(text1);

    TextView text2 = new TextView(this);
    text2.setText("Teset Header3");
    row0.addView(text2);

    TextView text3 = new TextView(this);
    text3.setText("Test Header4");
    row0.addView(text3);

    TextView text4 = new TextView(this);
    text4.setText("Test Header5");
    row0.addView(text4);

    tableLayout.addView(row0);

    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        TableRow tableRow = new TableRow(this);
        TextView tv0 = new TextView(this);
        tv0.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        tv0.setText("long test field 0");
        tableRow.addView(tv0);

        TextView tv1 = new TextView(this);
        tv1.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        tv1.setText("long test field 1");
        tableRow.addView(tv1);

        TextView tv2 = new TextView(this);
        tv2.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        tv2.setText("long test field 2");
        tableRow.addView(tv2);

        TextView tv3 = new TextView(this);
        tv3.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        tv3.setText("long test field 3");
        tableRow.addView(tv3);

        TextView tv4 = new TextView(this);
        tv4.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        tv4.setText("long test field 3");
        tableRow.addView(tv4);


        tableLayout.addView(tableRow);
    }

}
```

The longer the strings are for the text views, the more it crops off, however it's a horizontal scrollview, so it should just start at the beginning of the screen and add length to the end, which is scrollable, right?

This is what it ends up looking like with the current strings in **vertical/portrait orientation**:
[Vertical View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A40hX.png)

This is what it looks like in **horizontal**, it seems to fix since my screen is large enough for the data:
[Horizontal View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3QPyg.png)

If you have any questions, please ask!

Solved this by adding padding to the scrollview. It seems this is a common android bug.

Comment: Perhaps add some padding :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know will it work or not but try removing

> android:layout_gravity="center"

line from Relative Layout