# How to display data in the tableLayout

Tags: android, android-tablelayout

Based on the source code from this [webpage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18207470/adding-table-rows-dynamically-in-android), it doesn't work because the data isn't displayed in the table. I also have tried a similar code but it didn't work.

What part am I missing?

The result don't display without any error message.

Today, I'm a newbie in Android.

Info:
*using Android studio with API 25

Thank you!

**XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.jfdimarzio.myapplication.MainActivity">
</TableLayout>
```

**Java**

```
package com.jfdimarzio.myapplication;

import android.graphics.Color;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.TableLayout;
import android.widget.TableRow;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        init();
    }

    public void init()
    {
        TableLayout stk = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.activity_main);
        TableRow tbrow0 = new TableRow(this);
        TextView tv0 = new TextView(this);
        tv0.setText(" Sl.No ");
        tv0.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        tbrow0.addView(tv0);
        TextView tv1 = new TextView(this);
        tv1.setText(" Product ");
        tv1.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        tbrow0.addView(tv1);
        TextView tv2 = new TextView(this);
        tv2.setText(" Unit Price ");
        tv2.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        tbrow0.addView(tv2);
        TextView tv3 = new TextView(this);
        tv3.setText(" Stock Remaining ");
        tv3.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        tbrow0.addView(tv3);
        stk.addView(tbrow0);
        for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++) {
            TableRow tbrow = new TableRow(this);
            TextView t1v = new TextView(this);
            t1v.setText("" + i);
            t1v.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
            t1v.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            tbrow.addView(t1v);
            TextView t2v = new TextView(this);
            t2v.setText("Product " + i);
            t2v.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
            t2v.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            tbrow.addView(t2v);
            TextView t3v = new TextView(this);
            t3v.setText("Rs." + i);
            t3v.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
            t3v.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            tbrow.addView(t3v);
            TextView t4v = new TextView(this);
            t4v.setText("" + i * 15 / 32 * 10);
            t4v.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
            t4v.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            tbrow.addView(t4v);
            stk.addView(tbrow);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: There is no error message showing. There is no result displaying. That is something.

Comment: Try adding this at the end of your init method. `stk.invalidate();`

Comment: No differnece when I use the code stk.invalidate():

Comment: Can you retrieve a table in you android studio when you use the code above?

Comment: I think it's working, just set the background of your table to black. You're just not seeing the resutl.

Comment: When I got your advice i gave a new reflektion and I didn' think about changing the color of the text to black. It works. Thank you guys for your help!