# can i make the table layout dynamically? is there a method which takes how much rows nd columns i need?

Tags: java, android

i want to create  the table **dynamically** , now the number of *rows* and *columns* are saved in the respective *integer* variables.
please tell me the way i can create the  table **programatically** in android because number of rows and columns are not fixed .

what i tried so far is below...
is there any method to create table with given dimensions(***rows*** and ***columns***)?

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        TableLayout tl = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.tableLayout1);
        TableRow row = new TableRow(this);
        TextView tv = new TextView(this);
        tv.setText("This is text");

        tl.addView(row);
        row.addView(tv);

    }
```

Comment: sure you can: `TableLayout tl = new TableLayout(this)`

Comment: how i can dynamically add columns ?

Comment: Did you try this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/18207894/1488705

Comment: add them to `TableRow` - it is all described in the [TableLayout dcos](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TableLayout)

Comment: thanks a lot VicJordan i found this: `TableRow[] tr_head = new TableRow[productsList.length()];` helpful from there . have a good day sir!

Comment: m going to try bro Jatin Wadhavana

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution

```
int yourRowCount = 12;
int yourColumnCount = 12; 


private void createDynamicTable(int yourRowCount) {
    TableLayout tableLayout = new TableLayout(this);

    for (int i = 0; i < yourRowCount; i++) {
        tableLayout.addView(createRow(yourColumnCount));
    }
}


private TableRow createRow(int yourColumnCount) {
    TableRow tableRow = new TableRow(this);
    for (int i = 0; i < yourColumnCount; i++) {
        TextView textView = new TextView(this);
        textView.setText("TextView" + i);
        tableRow.addView(textView);
    }
    return tableRow;
}
```

just call

createDynamicTable(yourRowCount);

Comment: thanks a lot @Vishnu sir u just made my day!!