# Android studio: fill a dynamic table with data from resultset

Tags: android

I'm new to Android development. I want to fill a dynamic table with the data from a result set of a sqlite database. I dont know how to code it. Help me please.

Comment: You should give more information about this issue if you whant concrete answer

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding Table rows Dynamically in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18207470/adding-table-rows-dynamically-in-android)