# ScrollView cannot be scrolled?

Tags: android, android-scrollview

I need display data with table layout. I used the code from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18207470/adding-table-rows-dynamically-in-android) as starting point:

MainActivity.java

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.widget.TableLayout;
import android.widget.TableRow;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        init();
    }

    public void init() {
        TableLayout stk = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.table_main);
        TableRow tbrow0 = new TableRow(this);

        TextView tv0 = new TextView(this);
        tv0.setText(" Sl.No ");
        tv0.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        tbrow0.addView(tv0);

        TextView tv1 = new TextView(this);
        tv1.setText(" Product ");
        tv1.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        tbrow0.addView(tv1);

        TextView tv2 = new TextView(this);
        tv2.setText(" Unit Price ");
        tv2.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        tbrow0.addView(tv2);

        TextView tv3 = new TextView(this);
        tv3.setText(" Stock Remaining ");
        tv3.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        tbrow0.addView(tv3);
        stk.addView(tbrow0);

        for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++) {
            TableRow tbrow = new TableRow(this);
            TextView t1v = new TextView(this);
            t1v.setText("" + i);
            t1v.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
            t1v.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            tbrow.addView(t1v);
            TextView t2v = new TextView(this);
            t2v.setText("Product " + i);
            t2v.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
            t2v.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            tbrow.addView(t2v);
            TextView t3v = new TextView(this);
            t3v.setText("Rs." + i);
            t3v.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
            t3v.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            tbrow.addView(t3v);
            TextView t4v = new TextView(this);
            t4v.setText("" + i * 15 / 32 * 10);
            t4v.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
            t4v.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            tbrow.addView(t4v);
            stk.addView(tbrow);
        }
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:background="#3d455b"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        >

        <HorizontalScrollView
            android:id="@+id/hscrll1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TableLayout
                    android:id="@+id/table_main"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"></TableLayout>
            </RelativeLayout>
        </HorizontalScrollView>
    </ScrollView>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

And here's the output on simulator:

[image]

It starts at item #12 (should have been at #0). And it cannot be scrolled. How to fix this?

Comment: Set scrollview height to something that is not wrap_content

Comment: Should not use `wrap_content` for width or height.

Comment: `ScrollView` works for me without `horizontalscrollview` in `xml`

Comment: Try setting the height of your `RelativeLayout` to `wrap_content` because its direct parent is also wrapped

Answer (score 1):

```
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:background="#3d455b"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    >
```

change the above to:

```
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    android:background="#3d455b"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    >
```

basically wrap_content is wrong for a scroll view, also you had a layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf constraint which caused the weird positioning of your scroll view... you were basically asking android to center the scrollview to the top margin of your screen ie your scroll view would literally appear starting half way ( bottom needs to align to top and top also needs to align to top according to your code). lastly align parent left is useless in constraintlayout, it is not an error but it basically is useless