# Make a table from user input in Android App

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am currently making an expense tracker on Android Studio. it is my first time so I'm not too experienced and am not expecting a fully coded answer, but maybe some guidance as I have not been able to find any resources online for my particular question.

So I know how to get user input, which in my case would be something like `Amount Spent:` and `Location`... etc. The only thing I am not familiar with is how to add/append this data to a table in Android.

For example, the table would look like this:

[image: Table]

The user input would then be added to the table depending on the header.

Comment: There are quite a few options for drawing table like Views, but which one to use depends on a number of factors, like the features you want (Sticky column and or row headers), the size of the data to be displayed and what you want to happen when there is not enough space to display it all on screen at once. Efficiency or the ability to print/save the whole table, etc. It might be worth updating your question with a picture of a sketch of the table layout you want to achieve.

Comment: Even if you may not expect a fully coded answer (...), we'd expect a question, which can actually be answered in a way, which enables one to determine a correct answer. While this question most certainly doesn't fall into this category. Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking

Comment: @MartinZeitler apologies for the lack of description. i have edited my post and maybe this would provide further context. apologies if it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

I hope it will be helpful for you although in your post there is a few lack of description

[Adding Table rows Dynamically in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18207470/adding-table-rows-dynamically-in-android)

Comment: This probably should have been a comment. While I think that there might not even be a table yet.

Comment: Sorry i cannot comment on main post because of low reputation, i only can comment on own answer.

Comment: I know; maybe better answer a few posts until you reach a 100 XP; no link-only answers, if possible (actually the question above could also be closed as a duplicate of that).